# Vue.JS - Property value based on another property + string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a re-usable Vue.JS component, `DonutChart`.

```js
<donut-chart
    :chartName="graphPrefix + 'PerformanceDay'"
/>
```

`graphPrefix` is a property with value `site1` in this case. I use `chartName` for the `div id` in `DonutChart`.

I'm trying to get the value to be `site1PerformanceDay`. What is the proper approach?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use spaces.

```js
<donut-chart
    :chartName="graphPrefix+'PerformanceDay'"
/>
```